# What are AWAY and APART modifying here?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbials, grammatical-roles, measure-phrases

I wanted to ask a question about the adverbs *away* and *apart*.

- The villages are miles apart.
- The exam is only two weeks away.
- It is three days apart.
- It is five kilometers away/apart.

*Away* and *apart* are supposed to be adverbs right? So they must be modifying either adjectives, adverbs, or verbs -- right?

What do they modify in these examples?

FIrst example, *miles apart*: does *apart* modify *miles* (which is a noun)?

Same thing goes for *away*, like *two weeks away*.  *Two weeks* is a noun.

Comment: I suggest you have a good look at a dictionary, such as Webster or Cambridge, both available online.  You will find that ‘apart’ can be used as an adverb, but also as an adjective and even a sort of preposition.

Comment: @Tuffy Actually, these words are never adverbs, but then that's the punishment you get for looking up grammar info in a dictionary.

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm, I wonder.  So we have ‘take up’, ‘take down’, ‘take apart’ and ‘take out’:  three off the four uses are adverbial but one, ‘apart’, is not.  It is, I think, derived from French ‘à part’, which seems pretty adverbial to me.  and which, in turn, comes from the Latin ‘ad partem’.

Comment: @Tuffy The Latin is irrelevant, but suppose it wasn't: *ad partem* is a preposition phrase. (Most of the greatest misunderstandings about  English grammar derive from the fact that people think that is should have Latin gramar when it is a  different language, and therefore *cannot* have the same grammar)

Comment: @Tuffy No, none of those is adverbial, old bean, they are all prepositional, and they are all Complements of the verb. A big clue there is that they all describe the location of an object noun phrase. Adverbs don't do any of that

Comment: @Araucaria I am puzzled by what you say in your answer, where you describe ‘away’ as a specialised adverb?

Comment: @Tuffy OOoops. Thanks for that. Good catch. Huge typo. That should have read *right* and *straight*. As in *I took them straight out*, *Do it straight away*, etc. Have edited.

Comment: It is thee days apart? Apart from what?

Comment: @Araucaria Suppose it weren't. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some call *away* and *apart* adverbs. They can be adverbs, but they don't always work that way, and they have different meanings and grammar.

All the examples of *away* and *apart* in the Original Question occur in **[measure phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/465696/15299)** -- *miles apart, two weeks away, three days apart*, etc. These phrases involve a quantifier, either overt like *two* or understood like *(several) days*, and a quantity like distance, time, weight, and optionally (as here) something that indicates specifics about the quantity that is being measured.

This something extra can be *away*, which means *away from* some zero point like *now* or *here*, and refers to the distance to be covered or the time to be expended (or the fare money to be collected, as in *Chicago is $18 away*) in traveling to a place. *Away* is asymmetric -- it only goes in one direction:

- *Scranton is 30 minutes away (from Utopia)*
  means it takes 30 minutes to go (from Utopia) to Scranton.
  However,
- **Scranton and Utopia are 30 minutes away*
  is ungrammatical. *Away* requires a singular referent, not plural.

This extra thing can also be *apart* (as well as *long, wide, tall, old,* and many more). *Apart* comes from *part* and it is used to refer to things that occur together, as in the idioms *come apart, rip apart, fall apart,* etc.

In a measure phrase, *apart* requires a plural referent:

- *Scranton and Utopia are 30 minutes apart*
  is perfectly grammatical, but
- **Scranton is 30 minutes apart from Utopia*
  is not.

As for what modifies what, don't worry about it.
The definition of adverbs they gave you is full of holes.

Comment: Tahnk you for the explanation, so as I understand it, you are saying that these constructions like "five miles apart" "three weeks away" etc., are constructed by 
1) a quantifier, like a number, 
2) a quality, like time and distance, 
3) and some extra word like away, apart etc.

it is three(quantifier) weeks(quality) away(the extra word)

Comment: @SebastianPerez Don't forget ***ago***, as in *two weeks ago* looking back, contrasting with *two weeks away* looking forward.

Comment: That's not the only way they're used, and that's not a comprehensive description. The point is that you need to look at constructions, not individual words. Words occur in patterns.

Comment: "Scranton and Utopia are 30 minutes away" How is this ungrammatical? It sounds perfectly normal to me; it means that both of them are 30 minutes away from the present location.

Comment: That's true. But it's a different sense of _away_, meaning _away from here_, which shifts center, whereas _apart_ doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they aren't adverbs—despite what you might read in a dictionary.

There are a number of clues here:

- they primarily describe spatial relations, but can also be used to describe temporal ones
- they can be used to describe noun phrases, and can exist as Complements of the verb *BE*
- they can be modified by the specialised adverbs *right* and *straight*
- they don't have any typical adverbial suffix and don't have any homophonous adjectives either
- the phrases they head can postmodify nouns and noun phrases
- they can't be straightforwardly modified by the adverb *very*

One atypical property they have is that they don't occur before noun phrases. This is because they are intransitive prepositions.

In the Original Poster's examples they do not modify anything—and, indeed, this is an important point. It's because they are Locative  Complements of the verb *BE*, and not Modifiers, that we know they are not adverbs.

For more information about intransitive pepositions, see either of the following:

- *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Rodney Huddleston & Geoffrey Pullum, 2002.
- *Oxford Modern English Grammar*, Bas Aarts, 2014.

Comment: The reason that the funny *a-* words cannot appear in the normal "attributive" position to the left but only to the right or predicatively is simply because they began life as normal right-branching prepositional phrases that later got smooshed together into single words--but once done we never switched their syntactic chirality from right to left. That's why you never find asleep people with akimbo legs away three feet from the bed, only ever people asleep with legs akimbo three feet away from the bed. The effaced former preposition was usually *on* but sometimes other things like *at*.