# Inverse relation of dependency

Tags: word-choice, interpersonal-relations

I am looking for a word that is the reverse of the dependant relation.

For example:
If Bob financially/physically/.... depends on Alice, Bob is a dependant of Alice and Alice is a ..... of Bob.

Any input?

Comment: Dependency in the computer science sense. Patron in an artistic sense. Enabler in a substance abuse sense. Others in other contexts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does enabler have a negative notion associated? Otherwise, I think for my situation that suits the best.

Comment: Yes, it does. The enabler *enablers* the person’s dependency, which in the context “enabler” is used, is universally bad.

Comment: Perhaps "benefactory"

Comment: "benefactor" is the usual noun, not benefactory.

Comment: _Sponsor_ might also be used, in most contexts where _patron_ could be. However, _Sponsor_ has a broader meaning.

Comment: As noted, "dependent" has a lot of meanings in a lot of contexts. That's because [it's a Metaphor](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400802/15299). The original source is of something hanging from something else in a gravitational field. If the connection fails, the dependent thing falls. Substitute your favorite force for gravity, your favorite abstraction as the connection, your favorite values for _f=ma_, and compute. The fact that it has so many possible inverses is a result of its being used in so many different contexts metaphorically. There is no single inverse term.

Comment: *Caretaker* or *caregiver* are used when the level of dependency is very high (that is, when the dependent person requires assistance for very basic tasks). It's kind of funny that a pair of words ending in *-giver* and *-taker* are synonyms, but that's English for you.

Comment: Come on now: the opposite of dependent is independent. Bob is financially independent of Alice. It's dependence and independence.

Answer (score -1):

You may use ***patron*** in many circumstances like this.

> *patron* = a person or group that gives money or support to a person, an activity, or an organization
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patron%3C%3C)

> *patron* = one that uses wealth or influence to help an individual, an institution, or a cause
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patron)

The word has a long history, going back to Roman times. Your example of a *dependant* may be regarded as *client*:

> Clientship, Latin Clientela, in ancient Rome, the relationship between a man of wealth and influence (patron) and a free client; the client acknowledged his dependence on the patron and received protection in return. This sort of relationship was recognized in law as early as the 5th century BC; by the 1st century BC it had become hereditary. Freed slaves were automatically clients of their former owners. The patron might support his client in the courts or supply him with daily food, often converted into cash (sportula). The client was expected to show deference to his patron, especially by calling upon him each morning (salutatio) and by aiding him in his private and public life.
>
> [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/clientship)

Comment: A late-coming downvote is a complete mystery to me. Why a reasonably argued answer is not acceptable should be explained to the PO, preferably with references and reasons that refute my arguments.