# What is the origin of "home free"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I always assumed that the idiomatic phrase *home free* had its origin in baseball, and at least one relevant dictionary seems to confirm this.

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*, Houghton Mifflin 1997 ([online](https://books.google.com/books?id=l_LxuR1jMVgC&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q&f=false))
**home free** In a secure or comfortable position, especially because of being certain to succeed [...] This expression probably alludes to safely reaching baseball's *home plate*, meaning one has scored a run. [Mid-1900s]

But a different dictionary suggests the idiom is used in both America and Australia, which is easily confirmed by examples from Australian publications (emphasis in examples is mine):

*Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms*, Cambridge University Press 1998 ([online](https://books.google.com/books?id=CqxfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA195#v=onepage&q&f=false))
**be home free** *American & Australian*
to be certain to succeed at something because you have finished the most difficult part of it [...]

[Australian Broadcasting Corporation](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2012-06-29/saul---iraq-war/4098652):
"The servile, unquestioning friendship with George Bush, which dragged our government into Iraq and saw it defend Guantanamo Bay, is just another distant chapter in our feted alliance history. The Australian government lawyers who said it was legal are also *home free*."

[Sydney Morning Herald](https://www.smh.com.au/articles/2003/11/21/1069027301870.html):
"Another round of Senate estimates questions next week and the week after a new AFP brief to the DPP on possible criminal charges means Reith is still not *home free*."

Given that baseball is, in my understanding, a little-known sport in Australia, this appears to call into question the assumption that *home free* originated with this sport. What is the best available information we have about the origin of the phrase?

Comment: OED says *home free* is "originally US" ... but then, of course, it went elsewhere, even places where baseball is unknown.

Comment: I always related this to ["hide n' seek"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide-and-seek)...also _oxen free_, which I never understood.

Comment: Yeah, I would associate it with "hide n' seek".

Comment: I know very little about baseball, but have found this since I asked the question: [David Burke, The Slangman Guide to Biz Speak 2, pg. 200](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvWhabT2I3wC&pg=PT210#v=onepage&q&f=false)
**home free (to be)** *exp.* to be assured of attaining one's goal. [...] *Origin:* In baseball, said of a player who is certain to reach home base and score a point.

Comment: Baseball isn't a particularly big sport in Australia, but it is still very well known here. The phrase could easily have originated in reference to baseball in the US, and still ended up in relatively common use in Australia.

Comment: The earliest instances of *home free* in Australian publications I have found so far are from the 1990s. [Practical Punting, September 1994](https://practicalpunting.com.au/pp-online/greyhounds-and-harness/greyhounds/range-of-form-analysis-techniques/dog-box-blues-19940919):
"Most greyhounds prefer the inside 1 and 2 boxes, which are obviously close to the rail. If they can clear the first turn, they are often *home free*."

Comment: [Hansard 14 May 1996 - Queensland Parliament, page 1049](https://www.parliament.qld.gov.au/documents/hansard/1996/960514ha.pdf):
"An awful set of circumstances was in place -- at least for a while until the Minister started to bring down one poorly drafted regulation after another --that meant that the people who had complied were required to uphold the standards and those people who had not complied were *home free*, without any effective standards being applied to them."

Comment: *OED* provides an 1896 quote from *Dialect Notes* v1, p396, for the use in sports and games: "In hi-spy and similar games a player is said to be home free when he ‘touches the gool’ before it is touched by the person who is ‘it’." The use in sports and games likely derives from much earlier use (e.g., 1569) with reference to prisoners and slaves delivered 'home free'.

Comment: @JEL: The [source cited by the OED](https://books.google.com/books?id=-VtFAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA397#v=onepage&q&f=false)  at Google Books.

Comment: i can't believe the term doesn't originate from baseball! but i can settle with that at least the term is related to baseball

Answer (score 2):

It's a metaphor, and while it may have some use in baseball, it's more likely to have originated in children's games like hide-and-seek that have a "home" place which is the goal of players.

When a game ends, for instance, there is a characteristic call to bring in the other players, saying, essentially, everybody can come home without being caught. Where I grew up, it was something like "All-ie, all-ie outs in free" (though some said "oxen free" or "ocean free" because it was funnier, or more traditional).

*Home free*, by itself, is rather like [the first (good) meaning of *all downhill from here*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198952/15299); it means that the hard part is over, and we're all good from now on.

Comment: I just thunk a thought...any chance that "All-ie, all-ie" has an etymology going to the French "_Allez...Allez_"?

Comment: ¿Quien sabe? On va voir.

Comment: @Cascabel - Nah, it's "Olly, Olly in free!"

Comment: Or  [Olly olly oxen free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olly_olly_oxen_free).

Comment: The earliest instance of *home free* I have been able to find with Google Books so far is baseball-related: [The Free Lance-Star, Frederickburg, Va., Saturday, September 7, 1957, page 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=rOFLAAAAIBAJ&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false) : "In the American, New York's Yankees, apparently *home free* a while ago, are down to a 4½ game lead again."

Comment: Or [Ally Alley Oxen Free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZlyvOQTutk).  I'm also recalling a Peter, Paul & Mary song (can't remember which one) that ends with "Olly olly in free!"

Comment: How does one play hide-and-seek with a "home" place?

Comment: @AzorAhai - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide-and-seek

Comment: ah so it's more likely that this term and some baseball terms are based on the idea of 'home' rather than that this term comes from baseball? something like the ice cream sales and drowning or something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation#Third_factor_C_(the_common-causal_variable)_causes_both_A_and_B

Answer (score 0):

This is the phrase used by children playing ["hide n' seek"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide-and-seek) upon reaching ["home base"](https://www.britannica.com/topic/hide-and-seek-game).

> a hider must yell "free" when he touches base or he can still be tagged out. But if the seeker tags another player before reaching home base, that person becomes "it."

I do not know how that dictionary relates baseball home with "home free". The usual term upon reaching *home* (or any base) untagged in baseball is "safe".

There is also ["olly olly oxen free"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olly_olly_oxen_free), which I have never understood. It should be remembered that a child's dialect is usually based on the perceived language of adults , and is often misunderstood or mis-interpreted.

Comment: As soon as I can determine _when_ this phrase was _first_ used in the game, I will edit it in; but I suspect it goes back as far as when children played this game (in English), and that must be a very, very long time ago.

Comment: [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=home+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chome%20free%3B%2Cc0) *suggests* that the phrase in its current figurative use may have come into use around 1960, which jibes with Ammer's assertion that the origin dates to the mid-1900s. Given that the game of hide & seek has apparently been around for centuries, it is curious that figurative use would have started this late, and it is not clear what might have prompted it.

Comment: @njuffa Yeah, I would think that too, but I have problems with n-grams sometimes. It could have been in use for quite some time before being used in a journalistic sense.

Comment: Yes, it seems a rather childish expression.

Comment: I've always believed *olly oxen free* was from *all the outs in free*, but I can't remember whether I read something with evidence for that or just thought it sounded logical.